# JavaScript Function. Can someone help or explain why it logs 120? I see 20 based on my analysis

Tags: javascript

I would like to sum up all the elements inside the array covertedValue. Why I am getting a Nan result? whats wrong with the recursive function I have written?

```
function findOutlier(integers){

  var covertedValue = integers.map(x => x % 2);
  var total = 0;

  for (i=0 ; i<covertedValue.length ; i++){
    total = total + covertedValue[0] + findOutlier(integers.splice(1));  
  }

  console.log(total);

}

findOutlier([0, 1, 2]);
```

Comment: `5*4*3*2*1` equals 120.

Comment: What *was* your analysis?

Comment: 5*4*3*2*1 equals 120 looks like its going through a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this line create a function and a private alias to itself

```
var factorial = 
// create a variable named factorial in global scope
// it contains the function fac

                function fac(n) {
// fac is a function available only in the factorial var context

   return n < 2 ?                     // if n < 2
                  1 :                 // return 1
                      n * fac(n - 1); // else return n * fac(n - 1)
};

console.log(factorial(5)); 
// calls factorial(5) which is 5*fac(4) which is 5*(4*fac(3)) ...
```

note that the `fac` function is not available outside of itself

```js
var factorial = function fac(n) { return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1); };

console.log(fac(5));
```

---

This way of coding where a function call itself is called [recursive programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion) it can be hard to grasp at first but can be VERY powerful in some situations

recurcive programming can easily be used when the result of `func(n)` depend directly on the result of `func(n+x)`

---

the `cond ? then : else` structure is called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it's a way to make `if` in one line, can become messy very quick

---

as you noted in a comment : recursion can be replaced by a loop (it can be hard to do it sometime)

here's a more beginner way to write it

```js
function factorial(n) {

  if(n < 2) {
    return 1
  } else {
    
    let fac = 1;
    for(var i = n; i > 0; i--) {
      fac = fac * i 
// here fac takes the value of the precedent iteration
    }
// this whole loop is the same as i*fac(i-1) in the recurcive way
    return fac
  
  }
};

console.log(factorial(5));
```

Comment: Yeah definitely hard to gasp for a beginner like me :) but good to know how this recursive programming works :) . Thanks!